# $CA=I $ and $AB=I $ property of IMT

Tags: matrices

Why does the invertible matrix theorem state the inverse of an invertible matrix $A$ separately as a right and left inverse when the right and left inverse are equal?

Thank you

Comment: I have not seen that version of the theorem where they make that distincion, do you have a ref to it? The only reason I can think of why this is done is that non-square matrises do not have an inverse, but might have a left or a right inverse.

Comment: @Winther So for a non-square matrix that might represent the coefficients of an overspecified or under specified system, what does this non-square matrix having a left or right inverse mean for the solution? Does it mean there is one solution?

Comment: Just to clearify why you ask for, is your question for example why we have both Pt. 9 *and* Pt. 10 in the theorem [as stated here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html) ?

Comment: It's why we have Pt. 9 and Pt. 10

Comment: OK, then disregard my comment above. I don't think thats relevant. The theorem is just a list of things that holds if and only if a matrix is invertible. You might also ask, why are the other things listed there as we really only need point 1 for example (they are all equivalent). You are right that $CA=I$ and $AB=I$ implies $C=B$, but this is a result that needs to be proven (and is in the proof of this theorem)

Comment: True. It just seems that Pt 9 and 10 are more redundant than the others.  And there is no statement that the left and right inverse are equal, even though we know they are for a square invertible matrix.

Comment: You are right, the theorem does not say that they are equal - my bad. Anyway, I just view the theorem as a list of facts and I would not read much into the distinction here. One could make the same objection about Pt. 18 and Pt. 19: if $0$ is an eigenvalue then clearly the determinant is $0$ and visa versa. For students starting to learn about linear algebra one might not know all the relations in there so I guess its useful to just have all the points in there.

Comment: Yes, that seems equally as redundant. Thank you for your help.